# NSData.write triggers ECX_BAD_ACCESS on iOS 8

Tags: ios, nsdata, atomic

My app displays OpenStreetMap tiles (256*256 images), and caches them on the disk while the user browses the map.

On iOS 10, everything is fine, but on iOS 8, the app crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) if I don't write the NSData atomically. There is no problem to do it atomically, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Here is the relevant code I'm using:

```
private func putInCache(key:NSString, data:NSData) {

    // Get the path:
    let path:String = "\(self.imagesFolderPath)/\(key)";
    var success:Bool = false;

    // Save the image, if it does not exists:
    if(!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath:path)) {

        // Run in background:
        DispatchQueue.global().async {

            // Put the image in the memory cache:
            self.memoryCache.setObject(data, forKey:key);

            // Insert the row in the database:
            let success = insertDataInDb(...);

            // Then save the file (if the DB insertion succeeded):
            if(success) {

                data.write(toFile:path, atomically:false); // If I set atomically to true, it works.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does someones knows why there is a difference between writing the data atomically or not?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata):

> Atomic writes guarantee that the data is either saved in its entirety,
>   or it fails completely. The atomic write begins by writing the data to
>   a temporary file. If this write succeeds, then the method moves the
>   temporary file to its final location.

Probably, you are experiencing crash due to simultaneous attempts to write to the same path by different queues.